# Add a dot to the string in the form of a name, if there are characters in the name string

Tags: php, function

I want to create a function that can correct invalid string names. Sample case:

1. "ThOMas m aEro" will be "Thomas M. Aero"
2. "T M aEro" will become "T.M. Aero"
3. "thomas M. e." will become "Thomas M.E."

Here is the code that I have created using PHP:

```
function fixName($name){

    $step1 = str_replace('.', ' ', $name);
    $step2 = ucwords(strtolower($step1));

    $step3 = explode(" ", $step2);
    $step4 = "";
    foreach ($step3 as $part3) {
      $partName = trim($part3);
      if(!$partName) continue;
      if(strlen($partName) == 1){
        $step4 .= $partName . ".";
      }elseif($step3[0] == $partName){
        $step4 .= $partName . " ";
      }else{
        $step4 .= " " . $partName;
      }
    }
    return $step4;
}
```

Any better code suggestions for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly concise version of your function which relies mainly on regex replacements to get the job done:

```php
function fixName($name) {
    $output = preg_replace_callback(
    "/\b\w+\b/", function($m) {
        return strtoupper($m[0][0]) . strtolower(substr($m[0], 1));
    },
    $name);
    $output = preg_replace("/\b(\w)(?=[^.\w])/", "$1.", $output);
    $output = preg_replace("/\b(\w\.)\s*(?!\w{2,})/", "$1", $output);
    return $output;
}

$input = array("ThOMas m aEro", "T M aEro", "thomas M. e.");
foreach ($input as $inp) {
    echo $inp . " => " . fixName($inp) . "\n";
}
```

This prints:

```
ThOMas m aEro => Thomas M. Aero
T M aEro => T.M. Aero
thomas M. e. => Thomas M.E.
```

For an explanation, there are 3 replacement steps used above.  The first puts all words into camel case, with the first character being capitalized, and all subsequent characters in lowercase.  Next, we add a trailing dot to all single characters.  Finally, we remove whitespace in between clusters of single letter initials.  Here are the steps as applied to one of your test inputs:

```
T M aEro    original input
T M Aero    camel cased
T. M. Aero  add dots after single letter intials
T.M. Aero   trim whitespace between clusters of initials
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I was so motivated to learn more about regex